# Work on Google Apps Script locally on Ubuntu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ubuntu-16.04, clasp

I need to work on an existing Google apps script project that I received from Github. I understood how to work with the code on the Google web IDE, but it is not convenient since I have to create all the files manually and cannot have the advantages of Github.

I am looking for a way to work locally on the code. I saw that it seems possible with clasp but I couldn't install it on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried [the following link](https://github.com/clasp-developers/clasp/wiki/Build-Instructions) for example.

Is there a way to to do it? Whatever the IDE, as soon as I can work locally I will be satisfy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the `clasp` that will work with apps script. That refers to a Common lisp implementation. You're looking for [`@google/clasp`](https://github.com/google/clasp).

Install it:

```
npm install -g @google/clasp
```